# get Erorr "Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")" python SqlAchemy in docker

Tags: python, sql-server, docker, sqlalchemy, prefect

I Have a python workflow using prefect
I run it in my local computer in work fine but when I build a docker container for and run in docker container it give me this erorr

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prefect/engine.py", line 1221, in orchestrate_task_run
    result = await run_sync(task.fn, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prefect/utilities/asyncutils.py", line 57, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(call, cancellable=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anyio/to_thread.py", line 31, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 937, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 867, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
  File "main.py", line 65, in getData
    df2=wd.write(table,df)
  File "/tmp/tmpypkmh1xjprefect/utils/write_data.py", line 48, in write
    if engine.has_table(TableName):
  File "<string>", line 2, in has_table
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 402, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3354, in has_table
    with self._optional_conn_ctx_manager(None) as conn:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3083, in _optional_conn_ctx_manager
    with self.connect() as conn:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3315, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 96, in __init__
    else engine.raw_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3394, in raw_connection
    return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3364, in _wrap_pool_connect
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2198, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    util.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3361, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 310, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 868, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 476, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 256, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 371, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 666, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 578, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 597, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/dbapi)
```

this is my write.py file that I use it to connect to msSQl

```py
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import numpy as np

class WriteToDatabase:
    def __init__(self)-> None :
        pass
    def createEngine(self):
        connection_url = URL.create(
            "mssql+pyodbc",
            username="user",
            password="3^hGcjs!*M4AEY^s",
            host="10.6.6.23",
            port=1433,
            database="JIRA_Issue_Database",
            query={
                "driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
            
            },
        )
        engine = create_engine(connection_url)
        return engine

    def removeDuplicate(self,df1,df2):
        df=pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates("Issue id",keep="first")
        return df

    # def removeComment(self,df):
    #     col_comment= [col for col in df.columns if "Comment"  in col or "Attachment" in col]
    #     dfCleanColumn= df.drop(col_comment,axis=1)
    #     return dfCleanColumn
    def addMoreId(self,ids):
        if len(ids)==1:
            return np.array([ids[0],"Dummy Id"])
        return ids

    def write(self,TableName,df):
        #drop duplicate column
        
        engine=self.createEngine()
        df2 = df.loc[:,~df.T.duplicated(keep='first')]

       
        if engine.has_table(TableName):
            print("getting data from database...")
            with engine.connect() as connection:
                q='''  SELECT [Issue key]
                        FROM [{tableName}] 
                        WHERE ( Created >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())) OR ( Updated >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())) OR ( Resolved >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()))'''.format(tableName=TableName)

                # remove data that may duplicate when we add new data
                result = connection.execute(q)
                new_key=df2["Issue key"].values
                result=np.array([ i[0] for i in result.all()])
                all_key= np.concatenate((result,new_key))
                all_key=np.unique(all_key, return_index=False)
                # print(all_key.shape,result.shape)
                
                query="DELETE FROM [{tableName}] where [Issue key] in {ids}".format(ids=tuple(self.addMoreId(all_key)),tableName=TableName)
                connection.execute(query)

                print("table already exist: inserting data.....")

                #to avoid erorr when there is new column from data downlaod
                q_col= "SELECT NAME FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.[{tableName}]') ".format(tableName=TableName)
                cols=connection.execute(q_col)
                existing_cols= [col[0] for col in cols]
                df2 = df2[df2.columns.intersection(existing_cols)]

                print(df2.shape,len(existing_cols))
               
            
                df2.to_sql(TableName, engine,index=False,if_exists='append')

                

         
             
              
 

        else:
            print("table did not exist : inserting .....")
            df2.to_sql(TableName, engine,index=False,if_exists='replace')
        return df2
```

This is my docker file :

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /prefect-docker

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

- My computer os : Window 10

Do I need to setup something in docker container in order to allow it to connect with sql-server?

Comment: So if you `docker run -it --rm python:3.8-slim-buster cat /etc/os-release` you can see that it's based on Debian 10 Buster. Have you followed the instructions to install [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server - for Debian 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server#debian17) via your Dockerfile?

Comment: Thanks you , let me check and try that first

Comment: I have try this  but it show me this erorr  => ERROR [ 2/11] RUN sudo su                                                                                                                        0.2s
------
 > [ 2/11] RUN sudo su:
#4 0.174 /bin/sh: 1: sudo: not found

Comment: Why `sudo`? If you also `docker run -it --rm python:3.8-slim-buster whoami` you can can that it's already using the `root` user so don't need any further privilege escalation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed this.
The solution : I need to install  ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server - for Debian 10 in my docker container
Thanks to [alwayslearning](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390122/alwayslearning) for giving me the hint in comment section

This is my latest Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2
RUN apt-get install -y curl apt-transport-https
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev

WORKDIR /prefect-docker

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```